# Apollo federation can 2 services return different models for same method

Tags: graphql, apollo-federation

I have extended an entity and added a field to it like fieldA that returns a type interfaceA.  Is it possible to have different services return different implementations of that type.  like service one return implA and service 2 returns implB so when I run a query asking for something like

```
fieldA {
   ... on ImplA {
     call service A
}
   ... on ImplB {
     call service B
}
```

Can federation do something like that?

Comment: So I got this working if I have a service that adds fieldA to an entity then I declaire ImplA and ImplB.  I can then make another service that extends ImplB and federated will call that service to get the model.  The problem is it will call Impl A and ImplB sequentially because they are entities would be nice if you could get the query plan to load ImplA and ImplB in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

So I got this working if I have a service that adds fieldA to an entity then I declaire ImplA and ImplB in same service. I can then make another service that extends ImplB and federated will call that service to get the model. The problem is it will call Impl A and ImplB sequentially because they are entities would be nice if you could get the query plan to load ImplA and ImplB in parallel.